# React Maximum update depth exceeded error #185

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I am using `<MaterialTable />` to display data in the application i am building, i am expecting a prop to change in my redux store, and when it does, I want to set the title of the table to the expected prop and also use it as a param in an api call [there is always a default object in my redux store that has that prop]. This works fine on development, also works fine when i deployed... but sometimes it throws this error **Error: Minified React error #185; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=185 for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.** I don't know how to go about this, the application is already online

This is what my code looks like.

```
import { CheckOutlined, CloseOutlined } from '@material-ui/icons';
import Axios from 'axios';
import MaterialTable from 'material-table';
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import DocumentTitle from 'react-document-title';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Col, Row, Table } from 'reactstrap';

import { baseURL } from '../../../../action/api';
import { getAllWarebillRequests, getWarehouses, deleteWarebillRequest } from '../../../../action/BO/action.warehouse';
import { moneyFormater } from '../../../../utils/nairaFormater';
import IsAdmin from '../../../Components/hoc/admin-hoc';
import tableIcons from '../../../Components/Icons/Icons';
import { error, success } from '../../../Components/Notification/Notification';



const Modal = React.lazy(() => import("../../../Components/Modal/Modal"));

const AdminViewWareBill = (props) => {

  const tableRef = useRef(null)

  const [stocksShipped, setStocksShipped] = useState([]);


  useEffect(() => {
    tableRef.current && tableRef.current.onQueryChange();
  }, [props.selectedWarehouse.warehouseName])

  const view = (e, data) => {
    setStocksShipped(data[0].waybilledStocks);
  }

  const deleteWarebill = (ids) => {
    props.deleteWarebillRequest(ids).then(value => {
      tableRef.current && tableRef.current.onQueryChange()
      success("Success", "topRight", `Waybill Deleted Successfully`)
    }).catch(err => {
      if (!err) return error("Error", "topRight", "Oops... An error occured");
      error("Error", "topRight", err.data.message ? err.data.message : "Oops... An error occured");
    })
  }


  return (
    <DocumentTitle title="View Waybill">
      <div className="animated fadeIn">
        <Row className="justify-content-center">
          <Col color="success" className="mt-5 mb-5" xs="12" md="10" sm="12">
            <MaterialTable
              tableRef={tableRef}
              title={props.selectedWarehouse.warehouseName + "'s Waybill Request"}
              columns={[
                { title: "Number", field: "waybillInvoiceNumber" },
                { title: "Amount(₦)", field: "waybillInvoiceTotalAmount" },
                { title: "Staff Requesting", field: "sellerRequesting.sellerFullName" },
                { title: "Shop", field: "sellerRequesting.shop.shopName" },
                { title: "Date Requested", field: "createdDate" },
                { title: "Shipped", field: "isWaybillShipped", render: props => props.isWaybillShipped ? <CheckOutlined /> : <CloseOutlined /> },
                { title: "Date Shipped", field: "dateShipped", render: props => props.dateShipped ? props.dateShipped : "Not Shipped" },
                { title: "Received", field: "isWaybillReceived", render: props => props.isWaybillReceived ? <CheckOutlined /> : <CloseOutlined /> },
                { title: "Date Received", field: "dateReceived", render: props => props.dateShipped ? props.dateShipped : "Not Received" },
                { title: "Staff Issuing", field: "sellerIssuing.sellerFullName", render: props => props.sellerIssuing ? props.sellerIssuing.sellerFullName : "NIL" },
                { title: "Warehouse", field: "sellerIssuing.warehouse.warehouseName", render: props => props.sellerIssuing && props.sellerIssuing.warehouse ? props.sellerIssuing.warehouse.warehouseName : "NIL" },
              ]}
              data={query => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                Axios
                  .get(`${baseURL}/wareBill/byWarehouse?warehouseId=${props.selectedWarehouse.warehouseId}&page=${query.page + 1}&size=${query.pageSize}`)
                  .then(res => {
                    res.data.content.map(value => {
                      value.waybillInvoiceTotalAmount = moneyFormater(value.waybillInvoiceTotalAmount)
                      return value;
                    })
                    resolve({
                      data: res.data.content,
                      page: res.data.currPage - 1,
                      totalCount: res.data.totalNumberOfData,
                    })
                  })
                  .catch(err => {
                    if (!err.response) return reject(error("Error", "topRight", "Oops... An Error Occured"));
                    return reject("Error", "topRight", err.response.data.message ? err.response.data.message : "Oops... An Error Occured")
                  });
              })}
              editable={{
                onRowDelete: oldData => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                  props.deleteWarebillRequest(oldData.waybillInvoiceId).then(value => {
                    success("Success", "topRight", `${oldData.waybillInvoiceNumber} Deleted Successfully`)
                    resolve()
                  }).catch(err => {
                    if (!err) return reject(error("Error", "topRight", "Oops... An error occured"));
                    error("Error", "topRight", err.data.message ? err.data.message : "Oops... An error occured")
                    reject()
                  })
                })
              }}
              actions={[
                {
                  icon: tableIcons.RefreshOutlined,
                  onClick: () => tableRef.current && tableRef.current.onQueryChange(),
                  isFreeAction: true,
                  tooltip: "Refresh"
                },
                rowData => rowData.length > 1 ? null : ({
                  icon: tableIcons.Visibility,
                  tooltip: "View",
                  onClick: view
                }),
                rowData => rowData.length < 2 ? null : ({
                  icon: "delete",
                  tooltip: "Delete Multiply",
                  onClick: () => {
                    const ids = rowData.map(value => value.waybillInvoiceId).join(",");
                    deleteWarebill(ids)
                  }
                })
              ]}
              options={{
                search: false,
                selection: true,
                pageSize: 5,
                pageSizeOptions: [5, 10, 20, 30, 40]
              }}
            />
          </Col>
        </Row>

        <Modal width={700} handleCancel={() => setStocksShipped([])} isOpen={!!stocksShipped.length} title="Stocks Waybilled" wantFooter={true}>
          <Row style={{ maxHeight: "250px", overflowY: "scroll" }} className="justify-content-center">
            <Col md="12" className="mb-5 mt-2">
              <Table id="tabel2" hover bordered striped responsive size="sm" className="table-outline mb-0 d-sm-table" style={{ "minWidth": "40%", "textTransform": "capitalize" }}>
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Category</th>
                    <th>Quantity Waybilled</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  {
                    stocksShipped.length && stocksShipped.map((value, index) =>
                      <tr key={index}>
                        <td>{value.stockName}</td>
                        <td>{value.stockCategory}</td>
                        <td>{value.quantityWaybilled}</td>
                      </tr>
                    )
                  }
                </tbody>
              </Table>
            </Col>
          </Row>
        </Modal>
      </div>
    </DocumentTitle>

  )

}

const mapstateToProps = state => ({
  selectedWarehouse: state.warehouses.selectedWarehouse
})

export default connect(mapstateToProps, { getWarehouses, getAllWarebillRequests, deleteWarebillRequest })(IsAdmin(AdminViewWareBill));
```

edited to add the actual component

Comment: It sounds like something is causing an infinite re-render, but it's impossible to tell what the problem is from the info you've provided.

Comment: in a nut shell that's all there is to the component, added the actual component

Comment: Right, but something is causing a re-render of this component when new `props` get passed, and that's something you're not showing here and we don't know what and how this component exactly is being used.

Comment: `tableRef.current && tableRef.current.onQueryChange();` should be causing a re-render, but it does it once

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this same error. In my case, I was just returning a fixed object the `data` function:

```
{
  data: [],
  page: 1,
  totalCount: 0
}
```

then I changed to

```
{
  data: [],
  page: 0,
  totalCount: 0
}
```

and the error disappeared. So it seems that if you try to access a page that has no row, it will throw this error.